# Prove $\lim_{\infty }\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1} = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Please check my proof and point mistake

$$\left |\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}  \right |^{2}<\epsilon^{2} $$

$$ \frac{n}{n^{2}+2n+1}< \epsilon^{2} $$

$$ \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2} }< \frac{n^{2}+2n+1}{n}$$

If we suppose n> N and we choose $N\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2} }$

Then

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2} }< \frac{n^{2}+2n+1}{n}$$

Therefore

$$\left |s_{n}-0  \right |< \epsilon $$

Comment: If I were you I would always transfer to a corresponding real function and use calculus techniques. Then again your professor might get pissed off.

Comment: @Alephnull Transferring to the corresponding real function requires a certain lemma to be proven. If this is not done, the professor would rightly be pissed off.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122  Well the sequence is a SUBSET of the corresponding function so you would only have to prove that the two definitions of limit are compatible.

Comment: 0 is a very special number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working too hard.

Since
$\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}
< \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n}
= \dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}
$,
if we can choose
$n$ large enough
so that
$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}
< \epsilon
$,
then,
automatically,
$\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}
< \epsilon
$.

By elementary algebra,
$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}
< \epsilon
\iff
n > \dfrac1{\epsilon^2}
$
and we are done.

This is an example
of a general principle
when proving limits:
Lower order terms can
almost always be disregarded.

When this is done,
the resulting value of $n$
may not be the best,
but, if the goal is to show
that the limit exists,
that does not matter.

Comment: I used the same technique 3  - 4 times in my limit (see my profile for limit proof) and someone said I used it often.Then I  try another way.Thank for comment.So Is my proof  correct?

Comment: The OP may not have learnt rigging yet.

Comment: For these problems, I think they want an *explicit* formula for $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$. If this is the case, then your proof is not correct because you have an implicit formula for $n$.

Comment: @ Ian Miller: What do you mean by "rigging"?

Comment: Sorry, thats not the correct technical word for what I meant. The technique of replacing the expression with something bigger which still converges to the same value. My students talking about 'rigging the algebra so it works'.

Answer (score 1):

Minor stuff: You are missing some formal notation:

> $$\color{red}{\left|\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\right|<\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$$
>
> $$\color{red}{\because}\left |\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}  \right |^{2}<\epsilon^{2} $$
>
> $$\color{red}{\because} \frac{n}{n^{2}+2n+1}< \epsilon^{2} $$
>
> $$\color{red}{\because} \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2} }< \frac{n^{2}+2n+1}{n}$$

This next sentence is vague. Why are you supposing this? You should have a definition you are working form which should maybe be at the start. Something like:

$$\color{red}{\text{The sequence }s_n\text{ converges to }L\text{ if given }\epsilon>0\exists N\text{ such that }|s_n-L|<\epsilon\forall n>N}$$

> If we suppose n> N and we choose $N\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2} }$
>
> Then
>
> $$\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2} }< \frac{n^{2}+2n+1}{n}$$
>
> Therefore
>
> $$\left |s_{n}-0  \right |< \epsilon $$

Given the style you are using I would have finished off something like this:

$$\color{red}{\because n<\epsilon^2(n^2+2n+1)}$$

$$\color{red}{\because 0<\epsilon^2n^2-(1-\epsilon^2)n+\epsilon^2}$$

$$\color{red}{\text{Taking the positive root (as }n>0\text{) :}}$$

$$\color{red}{\because n>\frac{1-\epsilon^2+\sqrt{(1-\epsilon^2)^2-4\times\epsilon^2\times\epsilon^2}}{2\epsilon^2}}$$

$$\color{red}{\because \text{Let }N=\frac{1-\epsilon^2+\sqrt{(1-\epsilon^2)^2-4\times\epsilon^2\times\epsilon^2}}{2\epsilon^2}}$$

$$\color{red}{\text{So if }n>N\text{ then }\left|s_n-0\right|<\epsilon}$$

Comment: Wow thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

Rearranging gets $sqrt (n/(n+1)^2)$ . The sqrt goes to 0 when the function value goes to 0. Thus we consider $n/(n+1)^2$ which goes to 0 when its reciprocal goes to infinity. It is obvious the reciprocal goes to infinity when $n$ goes to infinity because it is just $n+1/n$    .

Comment: Can you please add in your TeX/MathJax.